# How to: dynamically select a table field name in a formula based upon a value set in a cell outside the table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table [TABLE1] in an Excel spreadsheet that begins in cell A3.  That table is structured as follows:

| Classification | Task Description | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Select |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class1 | Task 1 | 5 |  | 3 |  |  |
| Class1 | Task 2 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Class2 | Task 3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Class3 | Task 4 | 1 |  |  | 1 |  |

The [Select] column is intended to be used to filter the values I'm interested in.  It should contain a simple boolean (True/False) value.  I'm able to accomplish this by setting a formula for the [Select] column to something like this:

=NOT(ISBLANK(@[Q1]))

The goal is to be able to "change" the formula without having to manually edit the formula (i.e. I want to protect this cell so others can't muck up the formula), so what I want to do is to change that formula dynamically by specifying the quarter I want to see the data for in cell B1 (e.g., set B1 to 1 for Q1, 2 for Q2, etc.).  Then, I should be able to filter out the "False" values in the [Select] Column to reduce the visible rows to what I'm actually interested in.

That should change the formula to something like:

=NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("@[Q" & VALUETOTEXT(B1) & "]")))

but this doesn't seem to work.

NOTE:  My actual scenario is slightly more complicated -- the formula in the select column is actually looking at values from 3 different table columns -- 2 that I always want to look at if they're not blank and 5 other columns that I want to be able to switch between based upon the value in cell B1.  I've simplified the issue for this question.

Comment: The choose() function is one.

Comment: It is better to reflect actual problem. What is your excel version?

Answer (score 1):

Another (non-volatile) way to approach it is:

```
=NOT( ISBLANK( INDEX( Table1[@[Q1]:[Q4]], 1, $B$1 ) ) )
```

Comment: Oh! exactly same one I posted may 1 or 2 minutes difference.

Comment: LOL!  I just saw.  At first, I was wondering why INDIRECT is not working - I could swear I have done the same in the past and it worked, but I tried it and, indeed it does not, so I must be imagining that I did it. So, I learned something here - INDIRECT on an Excel Table field name is not going to work.  Perhaps I was thinking about the times that I parsed the values in the header and put into SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1):

Try `INDEX()` then return column based on value of `B1` cell.

```
=ISBLANK(@INDEX(Table1[[Q1]:[Q4]],,B$1))
```

[image]